# Show that if $X$ is compact, and if $A$ is a closed subset of $X,$ then $A$ is also compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Show that if $X$ is compact, and if $A$ is a closed subset of $X,$ then $A$(with the subspace topology ) is also compact.

**A HINT:**

Use the subspace topology to relate open sets in $A$ with open sets in $X;$ somehow you need to find an open cover of $X.$

**Still I am unable to solve it using the hints given, could anyone help me in solving it using the hints given?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ be an open cover of $A$, $U_i=V_i\cap A$ where $V_i$ is open in $X$, $(V_i)_{i\in I}\cup (X-A)$ is an open cover of $X$ and has a finite subcover $V_1,...,V_n, X-C$, $A=X\cap A)=(V_1\cup..\cup V_n\cup (X-A))\cap A= U_1\cup..\cup U_n$.

Comment: but $A$ is closed only, how do you know that it has a cover or does any set in the world has a cover?

Comment: $A$ has a topology thus  open covers example $(A)$, by definition, you have to show every open cover of $A$ has a finite subcover.

Comment: what is $C$? why you took the finite subcover of $X$ to look like this?

Comment: Is there a relation between $C$ and $A$?

Comment: Is $C $ a nonempty subset of $A$?

Comment: In the last line why did you substitute with a finite subcover of $X$ that is different than the one you mentioned in the second line? does the existence of the finite subcover of $X$ in the second line implies the existence of the finite subcover of $X$ in the third line?